# How can I launch you tube video in colorbox?

Tags: javascript, jquery, colorbox

I'm trying to use the colorbox (http://www.jacklmoore.com/colorbox/) jquery plugin to launch youtube videos in a lightbox.

This works fine on the examples page at the colorbox website, but when I try it out on my website, I doesnt work.

There are no errors in console and the lightbox opens up with nothing.

Example here:
http://codeplay.azurewebsites.net/colorbox/index.html

Here is how I am launching colorbox:

```
$.colorbox({
href: 'http://www.youtube.com/embed/v0EsVMAyZdI',
iframe: true,
maxWidth: "80%",
maxHeight: "80%"
});
```

Any ideas what is going wrong?

Comment: in the example page they use an anchor and assigned the colorbox to it

Comment: @JuanC. The documentation also states that you can pass a parameter, for using it on elements that are not an anchor tag. The plugin does not appear to function correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Do this on your Link:

```
<a class="youtube cboxElement" href="http://www.youtube.com/embed/VOJyrQa_WR4?rel=0&amp;wmode=transparent">Flash / Video (Iframe/Direct Link To YouTube)</a>
```

and in JS:

```
$(".youtube").colorbox({iframe:true, innerWidth:640, innerHeight:390});
```

Also View source of this page, which has many examples:
http://www.jacklmoore.com/colorbox/example2/

Comment: The OP mentioned the demo page -- he is trying to do this on an element that is not an anchor. The documentation says it is possible, but the plugin does not appear to be working correctly.

Comment: Chris is correct, the docs say that this should work but for some reason it doesnt work for me

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, you have to specify a width and height property for iframe elements.  Colorbox can't measure how large an iframe should be like it can other types of content, because it's not privy to what loads inside of the iframe.

Answer (score 0):

have you solved this yet?

If not here's a chunk:

```
<a class='youtube' href='http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VOJyrQa_WR4'>Business Cats</a>
<script>
$('.youtube').colorbox({iframe: true, width: 640, height: 390, href:function(){
    var videoId = new RegExp('[\\?&]v=([^&#]*)').exec(this.href);
    if (videoId && videoId[1]) {
        return 'http://youtube.com/embed/'+videoId[1]+'?rel=0&wmode=transparent';
    }
}});
</script>
```

Taken from: 
http://www.jacklmoore.com/colorbox/faq/#faq-youtube